# How to send data piece by piece using Flux?

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

I play with [baeldung tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-5-functional-web) from [github](https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/spring-5-reactive-security). 
I wanted to see how a browser retrieves data piece by piece. So I added my simple controller method:

```java
    @GetMapping("/flux")
    public Flux<Employee> getFlux() {
        return Flux.fromIterable(employeeRepository.employeeData.values())
                .delayElements(Duration.ofMillis(2_000))
                .take(3);
    }
```

But when I look at the browser network the data is retrieved in one chunk after 6 second delay.
How to do this correctly?

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you didn't mention Media type for the response.

Try this code.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/test",produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON_VALUE)
public Flux getMapping() {
    return Flux.interval(Duration.ofMillis(300)).map(f -> "HI");
}
```

Thanks,
Vimalesh